# Custom Resource Routes and Uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, upload, attachment

I have read and followed many different questions and forums on this topic but something is not right.  I am trying to do a simple image upload.  I have in my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= form_tag("/beers/newCal", method: "get", multipart: true) do %>
      <%= label_tag(:q, "Enter date (dd/mm): ") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>
      <br/>
      <%= label_tag(:q, "Enter event name: ") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:event) %>
      <br/>
      <%= submit_tag("Create Calendar Event") %>
      <br /> <br />
     <% end %>
     <%= form_tag("/beers/upload", multipart: true) do %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
def upload 
    uploaded_io = params[:picture]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
       file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

I am able to select the image for upload but it is not saving in the #{Rails.root}/public/uploads directory.  The file name is not written or anything.  When I comment out the upload function definition I do not get an error (which I expected to).

In my routes file I have tried

```
get 'beers/upload'
```

and

```
resources :beers
```

I have tried plenty of different combinations but this is the most basic way I have seen this done.

I am using ruby version 2.1.5p273 and rails version 4.1.8 on Amazon Ubuntu EC2.  Please tell what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have no submit button in your second form - how do you submit it? Just selecting a file will not submit it.

Further your action should be a post request, try

```
post 'beers/upload', to: 'beers#upload'
```

or even more dogmatic

```
resources :beers do
  collection do
    post :upload
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was referring to an example that never mentioned a submit button and I guess I took it too literally. Much appreciated.